# what is the difference between a differential structure and a maximal atlas?

Tags: differential-topology

I am afraid I am missing some subtlety here. 
they both have pages on wiki:

differential structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure

atlas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts